# BMC AR System importing XML using Python on Windows, error

Tags: python, xml

I wrote a bit of Python code to import XML files into the BMC AR system. I am not very familiar with this tool but the old command on Linux was.

```
java -cp /opt/bmc/ARSystem/api/lib/arapi7604_build002.jar:/opt/bmc/ARSystem/api/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/opt/bmc/ARSystem/api/lib/arapiext7604_build002.jar com.bmc.arsys.apiext.data.DataImport -x $4 -u $5 -p $6 -l "/opt/bmc/ARSystem/scripts/logs/GenericInterface.log" -o "$2/GENARXML.xml" -a $7
```

This was in a BASH file. In Python on Windows I have:

```
prog="D:\\Program Files\\BMC Software\\ARSystem\\Arserver\\api\\lib\\arapi91_build001.jar:D:\\Program Files\\BMC Software\\ARSystem\\Arserver\\api\\lib\\log4j-1.2.14.jar:D:\\Program Files\\BMC Software\\ARSystem\\Arserver\\api\\lib\\arapiext91_build001.jar com.bmc.arsys.apiext.data.DataImport"

subprocess.call(['java','-cp',prog,'-x',server,'-u',user,'-p',pasw,'-l',logfile,'-a',port,'-o',fullfile])
```

subprocess.list2cmdline returns: java -cp "D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\arapi91_build001.jar:D:\P‌​rogram Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar:D:\Progr‌​am Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\arapiext91_build001 .jar com.bmc.arsys.apiext.data.DataImport" -x d182a01ws465 -u Moteur -p password -l D:\DCCF\log.txt -a 3500 -o D:\DCCF\source/file.XML

I get this error: Unrecognized option -x
Actually any option returns this error, even though these parameters are consistent with the API.

Any suggestions? Thanks!
Gil.

Comment: You probably need to enclose any arguments which have spaces in with double quotes.

Comment: Thank Martin, that's what I do in the prog variable. I am getting different error messages depending if I use -cp or -jar after java and either "Unrecognized option -x" or "Could not find or load main class servername" It's a long command with three jar files, very confusing. I wonder if I'm using subprocess correctly or if the command is wrong, or if something is missing, maybe an environment variable on Windows..

Comment: as in `'"D:\Program Files....."'`  This uses a single quote with double quotes inside.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.. Same issue...

Comment: subprocess.list2cmdline returns: java -cp "D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\arapi91_build001.jar:D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar:D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\Arserver\api\lib\arapiext91_build001
.jar com.bmc.arsys.apiext.data.DataImport" -x d182a01ws465 -u Moteur -p password -l D:\DCCF\log.txt -a 3500 -o D:\DCCF\source/file.XML